# Make this fig in R

Tags: r, function, math, graph, figure

I want to replicate this figure in R, not the table that is just the data range and function information. The problem is with some of these functions, doing all of them in R. For example the inverse hyperbolic sine, ...?! Thank you

```
eq <- function(x) {arcsinh(x)}
tmp <- data.frame(x=1:50, y=eq(1:50))
p <- qplot(x, y, data=tmp, xlab="X-axis", ylab="Y-axis")
c <- stat_function(fun=eq)
print(p + c)
```

[image: mathematical functions and their figures]

Comment: `curve(acosh,from=1.1,to=10, xlim=c(0,10))`, etc. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of these are in base.

```
cosh(x)
sinh(x)
tanh(x)
acosh(x)
asinh(x)
atanh(x)
```

But this leaves out acsch(x), asech(x) and acoth(x). You can create these using log.

For example acsch(x) is equivalent to ln((1/x)+(sqrt(1+x^2)/abs(x))) , i.e

`plot(log(1/((-100:100)/100)+sqrt(1+(((-100:100)/100))^2)/abs((-100:100)/100)))`

The other two can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Answer (score 1):

There is no `arcsinh` function in base R:

```
?sinh   # note that the function name is `asinh`
```

This succeeds:

```
eq <- function(x) {asinh(x)}
tmp <- data.frame(x=1:50, y=eq(1:50))
p <- qplot(x, y, data=tmp, xlab="X-axis", ylab="Y-axis")
c <- stat_function(fun=eq)
print(p + c)
```

As would an effort with:

```
tmp <- data.frame(x=-50:50, y=eq(-50:50))
```

Comment: Then why does the page I referred you to say (at its very top): "They respectively compute the hyperbolic cosine, sine, tangent, and their inverses, arc-cosine, arc-sine, arc-tangent (or ‘area cosine’, etc)"?

Comment: Also explain why Eric Weinstein at Wolfram thinks they are the same: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicSine.html

Comment: arcsinh has an additional rotation to the transposition of asinh